# HTML: Image becomes very small on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble because the image becomes really small on mobile (or when I zoom in a lot in the browser). Why does this happen and how do I fix it? My HTML and CSS are below:

HTML

```
<section id = "s" class = "s-section">
<div class = "center">
    <h1> Title Title Title Title Title  </h1>
    <img src = "img/hands01.jpeg" width = 50% max-width = 200% object-fit = cover class = "float-left" padding-right = "2">
    <div class = "s-paragraph">
        <p> Insert text here askdjfalksdflksa dflkasj dflkasj dlkf asdlkfj aslkdfj alskd flkas jdjflkas dlkf asdlkdf lakss dflkas sdflkas dlkf aslkdf lkask dflkas dsflk aslsdfaslkdf jaslkdfj lkasdj flkasj dflkas dlkfaslkdkf lksadj flkas dflkasj dlkf aslkdf asklsdjf lksaj jdflkas dlfkas lskdf aslkd fslkd lkasd flkasd jl</p>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.s-section {
  padding-top:8rem; 
  padding-bottom:5rem; 
  background:#ef9000;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.s-paragraph {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: Regular Version]

[image: Mobile Version]

Comment: where is your html and css?

Comment: @Ji_in_coding edited it in.

Comment: I think some of the CSS in the code might be irrelevant since I experimented a lot of random stuff to try to fix this size problem but ultimately couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What's with the invalid inline styles that are not in style attribute? are those experimental?

Comment: @Huangism Yes they are

Comment: I think you've some special browser settings, I tested this website on my mobile phone and I've got the normal size.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Web Design and Development, I'd suggest to first read up on what media queries are [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_querieshttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Then, when you've gotten **at least a basic understanding** of media queries, move on to [grid systems in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

Once you have acquired all that knowledge, you will want to start building stuff with it - ***mobile responsive web stuff***

If you are afraid of frameworks, try this [grid-system only](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

If you are brave or have worked a bit with web frameworks before, you can move on to [Bootstrap's Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

A **commonly-used example** of Bootstrap looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            // Your content goes here
        </div>
         <div class="col">
            // Your content goes here
        </div>
         <div class="col">
            // Your content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the `<div class="col"></div>` element has different variations for different viewports - *a few examples* - `col-sm-2`, `col-lg-4`, `col-xl-12`, where the letters after "col-" refer to **the size of the viewport** and the numbers after that refer **to the amount of grid columns taken in the viewport**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use media queries?

Example:

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
   img{
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypuqfgek/7/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the % for width try defining them using a pixel count and then using media queries as @Denys Brustovskyi mentioned

```
<img src = "img/hands01.jpeg" width = 50% max-width = 200% object-fit = cover class = "float-left" padding-right = "2">
```

Like so:

```
<img src = "img/hands01.jpeg" width = 200px max-width = 400px object-fit = cover class = "float-left" padding-right = "2">
```

You can also try using the css:

```
.className {
background: url('filepathForPhoto.jpg');
background-size: cover;
width: 200px;
}
```